# Plotly graphs don't render on JupyterLab installed with Zero To JupyterHub (GKE)

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I was trying to render Plotly graphs on JupyterLab that I installed with Zero to JupyterHub on GKE. I followed the documentation here :

https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/

But still, graphs don't render directly on JupyterLab. Is there something else that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, you have to actually add a few more steps to the process. Here it is in full:

1. Install plotly `pip install plotly==4.9.0`
2. Install / Upgrade Jupyterlab widget `pip install jupyterlab "ipywidgets>=7.5"`
3. Install jupyterlab Extension `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.9.0`
4. OPTIONAL `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager plotlywidget@4.9.0`
5. OPTIONAL, Check extensions installed `jupyter labextension list`
6. Refresh the page of your jupyterlab
7. Build image by running `jupyter lab build`

Now you can open a notebook and run some sample plotly code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.show()
```

You should see the graph appearing ;)

Comment: Btw, when you are running each scripts, you might not see any outputs, it doesn't actually mean that nothing happened. 

Check with `jupyter labextension list` to make sure it's installed.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution that seems to work is:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))

fig.show(renderer="iframe")
```

It seems to work fine as well